# reference a form inside a selector in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

if i have this code in jquery:

```
var parentDiv = $(this).parent('.copyInstance');
```

inside this div there is a form.

how do i reference a form element inside this selector? i want something like this

```
  $.post($(parentDiv + " Form").attr('action'), $(parentDiv + " Form").serialize(),  function(data) {
    });
```

but this above doesn't seem to work

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @cletus - i added in what i am trying to hopefully explain the issue better.  let me know if this helps

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you explained what you were trying to do and why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reference a children element you can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) for example:

```
$.post(parentDiv.find('form').attr('action'), 
       parentDiv.find('form').serialize(),
    function(data) {
    });
```

Depending on how it is structured you could also use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) like:

```
parentDiv.children('form')
```

Comment: `parentDiv` is already a jQuery object, no need to clone it :)

Comment: I stand corrected, I was thinking about the "this" which should be encapsulate in $() since it otherwise does not work in some IE versions...

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options for this selector:

```
parentDiv.find('form') //finds any form at any level deep inside
parentDiv.children('form') //finds forms that are immediate children
$("form", parentDiv) //really calls .find() but easier on the eyes maybe?
```

Here's more info on [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`jQuery(selector, context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).